# Adding an attachment to an Email Alert

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I would like to add files attached to the record as an attachement to an Email Alerts triggered by a WFR.  Does anyone knows if this is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

See [Adding Attachments](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_CSH.htm#pages_email_templates_attachments.htm) for how to use `<messaging:attachment>` to include attachments in a Visualforce email template.

Comment: Can the `<messaging:attachment>` tag easily add files that are attachments on the record firing the the Workflow Rule, or would a custom controller be required to gather and attach those files?